# JavaScript JSON Schema

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation, schema

Is there in JavaScript or in modern frameworks as jQuery, **functions** to parse and check a JSON Data using a JSON schema?
I saw a couple JAVA's validators but im interested in using schemas in my web projects. How can I do it?

Comment: did you try googling? I came across this: http://www.asbjornenge.com/wwc/json_schema.html

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned jQuery but JSON schema was invented by the people of dojo toolkit.
I am using dojo too and don't know about jQuery.

This is basically the "reference validator":
https://github.com/kriszyp/json-schema

I am currently writing an open source visual schema editor and embed the above for
validation.

However - there are **9 JAVASCRIPT VALIDATORS** listed in the official reference:

http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Comment: I am not looking for JS validators, but JS FUNCTIONS that PARSES the JSON Schema.